# Python - issues with for loops to create dataframe with BeautifulSoup scrape

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm trying to create a new dataframe using BeautifulSoup to scrape a webpage. I'm following some code that worked in a different page, but it's not working here. My final table of data is blank, so seems it's not appending. Any help is appreciated. This is what I've done:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

allergens = requests.get(url = 'http://guetta.com/diginn/allergens/')
allergens = BeautifulSoup(allergens.content)

items = allergens.find_all('div', class_ = 'menu-item-card')

final_table = {}

for item in allergens.find_all('div', class_ = 'menu-item-card'):
    for row in item.find_all('h4', recursive = False)[0:]:
        for column in row.find_all('p', class_ = 'menu-item__allergens'):
            col_name = column['class'][0].split('__')[1]

            if col_name not in final_table:
                final_table[col_name] = []

            final_table[col_name].append(column.text)

df_allergens = pd.DataFrame(final_table)
```

This returns nothing. No errors, just empty brackets. I was able to retrieve each element individually, so I think the items should work but obviously I'm missing something.

Edit:
Here is what the output needs to be:

```
Item Name     Allergens
Classic Dig | Soy
Item2       | allergen1, allergen2
Item3       | allergen2
```

Comment: as a first look here, the website is loaded with `JavaScript`. `bs4` or `requests` will not help you to render the `JS`, you can use real browser like `selenium`. also please [edit] your question and show for us a sample of desired data. we might have a different solutions

Comment: I added what the output should be. I'd like the first column to be the Item Name and the second to be the Allergens list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to find all `h4` tags in every item. So make a change like below:

```
...
for item in allergens.find_all('div', class_ = 'menu-item-card'):

    for column in item.find_all('p', class_ = 'menu-item__allergens'):
        col_name = column['class'][0].split('__')[1]

        if col_name not in final_table:
            final_table[col_name] = []

        final_table[col_name].append(column.text)
...
```

Comment: This gave me results, so thank you for that. I do want the item name as the first column with the second column describing the allergens. How do I add another column with the item name?